# Alternative Proof to Proving Inequality Involving Slopes?

Tags: alternative-proof, slope

I was wondering if there was any other way of proving:

[Is this idea regarding slope true and how do you prove it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578290/is-this-idea-regarding-slope-true-and-how-do-you-prove-it?noredirect=1#comment5322224_2578290)

As I feel like I wouldn't be to catch that on say, a test, I was hoping if there is something else that would work in proving this.

Answer (score 0):

Let $AB$ lie on the $x$-axis in a new coordinate system. It's obvious that we can do that by translation and rotation, which doesn't change the slopes of any of the lines. Now the slope of $AB$ is $0$. From the condition we have that the slope of $BC$ is positive, so $C$ must lie above the $x$-axis, i.e. $C_y$ (the y coordinate of $C$) $>0$. But as $A_x < B_x$ the problem reduces to proving that the segment $AC$ lies above the segment $AB$, which is obvuously true. To make it more rigorous you can write that:

$$\text{slope of } AC = \frac{C_y - A_y}{C_x - C_y} = \frac{C_y}{C_x - C_y} > 0 = \text{slope of } AB$$

I don't think that this is that hard to notice during an exam.